# Async tasks executing in order?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My goal is to create a system that spawns an initial number of tasks(all the same). These tasks will grab and perform some background operation (from a DB) and then return, at which point a new task should spawn and do the same thing.

I have written the following code as a proof of concept, but it seems like all my tasks are executing 1 by 1, not in parallel.

Code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        int reqNumberOfThreads = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        try
        {
            await startSlaves(cts.Token, reqNumberOfThreads);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled Starting Threads");
        }
        cts = null;

    }
    async Task startSlaves(CancellationToken ct, int threadNum)
    {

        List<Task<int>> allTasks = new List<Task<int>>();// ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain. 
        for (int x = 0; x < threadNum; x++)
        {
            allTasks.Add(beginSlaveOperation(ct, x));
        }
        // ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain. 
        while (allTasks.Count <= threadNum)
        {
            // Identify the first task that completes.
            Task<int> output = await Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
            allTasks.Remove(output);
            allTasks.Add(beginSlaveOperation(ct, output.Result));
        }
    }
    public void performExampleImportOperationThread(int inputVal, int whoAmI)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(inputVal*10);
        System.Console.Write("Thread number" + whoAmI.ToString() + "has finished after "+inputVal.ToString()+" secs \n");
    }
    async Task<int> beginSlaveOperation(CancellationToken ct, int whoAmI)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);//Get command from microSched and remove it from sched
        performExampleImportOperationThread(randomNumber, whoAmI);//perform operation
        return whoAmI;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Thread number0has finished after 29 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 45 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 59 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 39 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 13 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 44 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 21 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 62 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 62 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 25 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 86 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 10 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 4 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 24 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 84 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 73 secs 
Thread number1has finished after 19 secs 
Thread number2has finished after 72 secs 
Thread number0has finished after 82 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `beginSlaveOperation` is marked as `async`, and you call it as if it were asynchronous, but you never actually `await` anything, so it is going to run synchronously.  (Which makes its caller run synchronously, and its caller run synchronously, and so on, so that your entire application is running synchronously.)

Marking a method `async` doesn't magically make it run in a new thread.  All it does is let you use the `await` keyword.  If you don't ever use it, all you've done is execute a bunch of code synchronously and wrap the result in a completed task.  You should even get a compiler warning for doing this.

You can fix that by having `performExampleImportOperationThread` be an `async` method and, instead of using `Thread.Sleep(...)`, use `await Task.Delay(...)`.  That await `performExampleImportOperationThread` to make `beginSlaveOperation` actually be asynchronous.

Or you could just not do everything that you're doing and replace it all with a call to `Parallel.For`, which can set a `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` to limit you to a specific number of concurrent threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the first part fixed my issue. As for the second part, I don't think a parallel.for call fits my current needs. I'm not looping though a predefined set of data, but instead  I'm setting up some background threads to check for work to do continuously (via a DB or other data source).

Comment: @Ramsey It doesn't matter that you don't have a set of data to iterate.  You can use `Parallel.For` to just run a block of code `n` times, just the same way that you can use a regular `for` loop to run a block of code `n` times, even if you don't have an array to iterate.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'd need to set N to infinity, because I want the tasks to always loop all the time to check for work to do. My goal is to have an application that I can throw on a new machine to easily make it a node to run jobs. 

In practice, performExampleImportOperationThread() will be one of several methods to run depending what sub-task the Task gets assigned from the DB.

Comment: @Ramsey That's not what the code you showed is doing; it is just looping from 0 to a number you read in from a textbox.  If you have entirely different code that you're working with then yes, it may require a different solution.  That said, whatever it is, I'm quite confident that there are easier ways that what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah this is PoC code, the number from the textbox is the maximum number of slave threads which would normally be in a conf file (real application will be a CLI app ran as a service) I loop to that number to create the initial threads and then add a new one when one completes. Instead of getting actual work from a DB table, they just wait a random amount of seconds to show they're running async.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code for future reference:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        int reqNumberOfThreads = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        try
        {
            await startSlaves(cts.Token, reqNumberOfThreads);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled Starting Threads");
        }
        cts = null;

    }
    async Task startSlaves(CancellationToken ct, int threadNum)
    {

        List<Task<int>> allTasks = new List<Task<int>>();// ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain. 
        for (int x = 0; x < threadNum; x++)
        {
            allTasks.Add(beginSlaveOperation(ct, x));
        }
        // ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain. 
        while (allTasks.Count <= threadNum)
        {
            // Identify the first task that completes.
            Task<int> output = await Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
            allTasks.Remove(output);
            allTasks.Add(beginSlaveOperation(ct, output.Result));
        }
    }
    public async Task performExampleImportOperationThread(int inputVal, int whoAmI)
    {
        await Task.Delay(inputVal*100);
        System.Console.Write("Thread number" + whoAmI.ToString() + "has finished after "+inputVal.ToString()+" secs \n");
    }
    async Task<int> beginSlaveOperation(CancellationToken ct, int whoAmI)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);//Get command from microSched and remove it from sched
        await performExampleImportOperationThread(randomNumber, whoAmI);//perform operation
        return whoAmI;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```